# Break ( stop ) button for a looping function in another button function ( Java )

Tags: java, loops, jbutton, break

I've been trying to make it so the buttonb ( Stop ) can break the loop, inside of the loop function. I just need the loop to stop or be broke by the buttonb ( stop ) button. Thanks. :) [ I've tried looking, but, to my avail have not found any results that could help me. ]

```
/*
 * 
 */

package stopwatch;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author C
 */

public class Stopwatch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private static int abc = 0;

    private static void print (int x, String b) {

        if ( x == 69 ) {

            System.out.println(b);

        }

        if ( b == null ) {

            System.out.println(x);

        }

    }

    private static void  changea(int val) {

        abc = val;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame aeeb = new JFrame("Stopwatch : Start");
        aeeb.setVisible(true);
        aeeb.setSize(50, 150);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        button.setVisible(true);
        aeeb.add(button);

        JFrame aeec = new JFrame("Stopwatch : Stop");
        aeec.setVisible(true);
        aeec.setSize(50, 150);

        final JButton buttonb = new JButton("Stop");
        buttonb.setVisible(true);
        aeec.add(buttonb);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            int x = 1;
            int msec = 0;
            int sec = 0;
            int min = 0;
            int hour = 0;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

            {

                if ( x == 1 ) {

                    print(69, "Stopwatch is running!");
                    x = 0;

                    int xd = 10;

                        while( xd < 20 ) {

                            if ( msec == 1000 ) {

                                sec = sec + 1;
                                msec = 0;

                            }

                            if ( sec == 60 ) {

                                min = min + 1;
                                sec = 0;

                            }

                            if ( min == 60 ) {

                                hour = hour + 1;
                                min = 0;

                            }

                            msec++;

                            if ( msec == 1000 ) {

                                sec = sec + 1;
                                msec = 0;

                            }

                            if ( sec == 60 ) {

                                min = min + 1;
                                sec = 0;

                            }

                            if ( min == 60 ) {

                                hour = hour + 1;
                                min = 0;

                            }

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);

                        }     catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Stopwatch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        }

                }

                if ( x == 0 ) {

                    print(69, "Stopwatch is running already!");

                }

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: There should **never** be a long operation inside an event handler. You are holding up the event dispatch thread. Besides, your loop is an endless loop, as `xd` is never changed. You should design a stopwatch using a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and always use event handlers only for short operations like setting a value in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag and set it to false when the stop button is pressed.

```
public class Stopwatch {
...
private boolean isRunning = false;
...
```

your loop inside of the Start button action:

```
  ...
  isRunning = true;
  ...
  while(isRunning) {
  ...
```

stop button:

```
   final JButton buttonb = new JButton("Stop");
   buttonb.setVisible(true);
   aeec.add(buttonb);
   aeec.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        isRunning = false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```
public class stopwatch{
    public boolean isOn = true;

    // stuff
    // loop:
    if(!something.isOn){
        break;
    }
    // rest of loop
}
```

And for the button press:

```
Stopwatch.isOn = false;
```